NSFW sci-fi comic where priests did child sacrifices on the first borns of each family
Some years back I read a NSFW webcomic serialised on their website where the story contained the following points -

The story was centred on a sandy planet
There was a section of people who were priests who performed sacrifices of the first born of each family
There were sexual scenes like BJ

It was in colour. I don't remember the year I read it clearly. It must have been 2020 or 2021.

In roughly which year did you read this? Also, was this in colour or black & white and what made it NSFW?

It was in colour and there were sexual scenes like BJ... I don't remember the year clearly. It must be 2020 or 2021
